# Ray-triangle intersection algorithm not working

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, raytracing

I am writing a raytracer using Java, but I ran into an issue with intersections between rays and triangles. I am using the algorithm given at [Scratchapixel](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/ray-triangle-intersection-geometric-solution), but it is not working properly.

I am testing it using the following code:

```
Face3D triangle = new Face3D(
        new Vector3D(-1, -1, 0),
        new Vector3D(1, -1, 0),
        new Vector3D(0, 1, 0)
);
Ray3D ray = new Ray3D(
        new Vector3D(0, 0, -1),
        new Vector3D(0, 0, 1)
);
log.info(triangle.getNormal());
log.info(triangle.collision(ray));
```

The expected output would be `0,0,0`, but instead it is returning `null` (no collision).

Full output:

```
17:31:56.013 [main] INFO  org.jrender.Main - Vector3D{x=1.0, y=0.0, z=0.0}
17:31:56.017 [main] INFO  org.jrender.space.Face3D - angle: 0.0
17:31:56.018 [main] INFO  org.jrender.Main - null
```

Collision method:

```
public class Face3D {
        // ... getters/setters etc.
        public Vector3D collision(Ray3D ray) {
        if (vertices.size() != 3)
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Normal can only be calculated on triangles");

        double angle = VectorUtils.dotProduct(normal, ray.getDirection());
        log.info("angle: " + angle);
        if (Math.abs(angle) < Constants.EPSILON) return null; // Constants.EPSILON = 0.001

        double d = VectorUtils.dotProduct(normal, v0);
        double t = (VectorUtils.dotProduct(normal, ray.getPosition()) + d) / angle;
        log.info("d: " + d + "; t: " + t);
        if (t < 0) return null;

        Vector3D intersection = ray.getPosition().copy().add(ray.getDirection().copy().multiply(t));
        log.info("intersection: " + intersection);
        Vector3D perpendicular;
        Vector3D edge;
        Vector3D distIntersection;

        edge = v1.copy().subtract(v0);
        distIntersection = intersection.copy().subtract(v0);
        perpendicular = VectorUtils.crossProduct(edge, distIntersection);
        if (VectorUtils.dotProduct(normal, perpendicular) < 0) return null;

        edge = v2.copy().subtract(v1);
        distIntersection = intersection.copy().subtract(v1);
        perpendicular = VectorUtils.crossProduct(edge, distIntersection);
        if (VectorUtils.dotProduct(normal, perpendicular) < 0) return null;

        edge = v0.copy().subtract(v2);
        distIntersection = intersection.copy().subtract(v2);
        perpendicular = VectorUtils.crossProduct(edge, distIntersection);
        if (VectorUtils.dotProduct(normal, perpendicular) < 0) return null;

        return intersection;
    }
}
```

Note: I am using vector.copy().subtract(), etc. because I have made the mathematical operations in-place, so making a copy is necessary for math operations

#### Utility methods that I have used

```
public class Vector3D {
    // ... getters/setters, etc.
    public Vector3D normalize() {
        return divide(Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z));
    }

    public Vector3D add(Vector3D v) {
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
        z += v.z;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector3D subtract(Vector3D v) {
        x -= v.x;
        y -= v.y;
        z -= v.z;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector3D multiply(double fac) {
        x *= fac;
        y *= fac;
        z *= fac;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector3D divide(double fac) {
        x /= fac;
        y /= fac;
        z /= fac;
        return this;
    }

    public Vector3D copy() {
        return new Vector3D(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

```
public class VectorUtils {
    public static Vector3D crossProduct(Vector3D first, Vector3D second) {
        return new Vector3D(
                first.getY() * second.getZ() - first.getZ() * second.getY(),
                first.getZ() * second.getX() - first.getX() * second.getZ(),
                first.getX() * second.getY() - first.getY() * second.getX()
        );
    }

    public static double dotProduct(Vector3D first, Vector3D second) {
        return first.getX() * second.getX() +
                first.getY() * second.getY() +
                first.getZ() * second.getZ();
    }
}
```

Comment: small note, not related to the problem itself: `new Vector3D(0, 0, 1).normalize()` does nothing, (0,0,1) is already normalized.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I know, I kept it like that because I was using other vectors for testing

Comment: Don't include any more than necessary though: your post should be a [mcve], not just "for us" but because forcing yourself to reduce until there's nothing let to reduce makes you discover the actual problem like... 99% of the time, because you know what your result should be, and there are only so many steps that lead from start values to that result once you've reduced the problem to its bare minimum.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the tip, I edited the question

Comment: If you see the cross product do different things, it's a good idea to find a few cases where you can show which input yields "the wrong output". Because provided you implemented both Vector3D.subtract and VectorUtils.crossProduct correctly (on that note: please show those in your post, because they're relevant to the problem) getting the face normal should always work (although the normal may point the wrong way if your faces don't all have the same chirality)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have edited the post to include the implementations for the math operations

Comment: You should have a look at the definition of a 3d cross-product. Your code is doing something very different.

Comment: @Gene Ohh, I assumed it meant multiplying the coordinates. I should have researched that. The code is working now, after fixing the cross product I just had to add a negative sign in an equation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was quite simple, I had my cross product implementation wrong, and after that I had to change one line of code.

I changed

```
double t = (VectorUtils.dotProduct(normal, ray.getPosition()) + d) / angle;
```

to

```
double t = (-VectorUtils.dotProduct(normal, ray.getPosition()) + d) / angle;
```

and it worked.